# Using the minus (-) key to buy an item in the Dota2 shop with an AZERTY keyboard layout

Tags: dota-2

I have an AZERTY keyboard layout. In Dota2, most hotkeys can be rebound in the in-game setting menu. However, for the shop, I have to resort to editing text files in the game folder to use AZERTY-compatible hotkeys instead of the QWERTY layout. So to buy the item on the first row and first column, I can press `A&` instead of `Q1` and it works as intended.

[image]

Except for the 11th row (minus key on a QWERTY) which does not appear to work. So if I buy something on the 11th row, for instance a sentry ward, I cannot do it with `A)` (instead of `Q-`). However, I can buy an observer ward (10th row) with `Aà` (for `Q0`) and I can buy a bottle (12th row) with `A=` (for `Q=`).

This is an excerpt from the `dotakeys_personal.lst` file found in `userdata`:

```
        "ShopTabConsumables"
    {
        "Name"      "ShopTabConsumables"
        "Action"        "shop_nav_to_tab 0"
        "Key"       "a"
        "Description"       "#DOTA_Shop_Hotkey_Consumables"
        "Version"       "2"
    }
    "ShopTabAttributes"
    {
        "Name"      "ShopTabAttributes"
        "Action"        "shop_nav_to_tab 1"
        "Key"       "z"
        "Description"       "#DOTA_Shop_Hotkey_Attributes"
        "Version"       "2"
    }
    "ShopTabArmaments"
    {
        "Name"      "ShopTabArmaments"
        "Action"        "shop_nav_to_tab 2"
        "Key"       "e"
        "Description"       "#DOTA_Shop_Hotkey_Armaments"
        "Version"       "2"
    }
```

etc.

```
        "ShopSlot10"
    {
        "Name"      "ShopTabSecret"
        "Action"        "shop_select_itemrow 10"
        "Key"       "0"
        "Version"       "2"
    }
    "ShopSlot11"
    {
        "Name"      "ShopTabSecret"
        "Action"        "shop_select_itemrow 11"
        "Key"       "-"
        "Version"       "2"
    }
    "ShopSlot12"
    {
        "Name"      "ShopTabSecret"
        "Action"        "shop_select_itemrow 12"
        "Key"       "="
        "Version"       "1"
    }
```

What is strange is that somehow the game understands the layout of "columns" on my keyboard: after editing the text file, if I press letter A, then the game understands that I am referring to the 1st colum (A in AZERTY, Q for QWERTY).

However, when it comes to "rows", the layout is messed up: even though the text file refers to the 1st column with the key `1`, if I press `&`, the game registers it as `1` and I get the item in the first row (exactly what I wanted). The problem really only arises with the 11th column, which is `-` in QWERTY and `)` in AZERTY. I have tried putting `)` in the text file. It does not work. I have tried putting `-`. It does not work.

So basically, I can buy every item except for the items on the 11th row.

If I use `KP_MINUS`, it works with the minus key on the keypad.

Comment: I mention the issue here: https://github.com/ValveSoftware/Dota-2/issues/415

Answer (score 1):

I believe that there might be a problem with your hotkeys.

Occasionally, when trying to bind a quick buy hotkey there can be an issue if that hotkey is already bound to perform another task.

In order to fix that you can try opening the dev console and unbinding the - key. I believe the command should be something like Unbind "-" or unbind "Minus".